# Compare position and elements of 3 different lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm trying to compare the position and elements of 3 different lists, to then save them in a new list, if at least 2 of the elements at the same position matched.

For Example:

```
a = [FF2, FF6, FC4]
b = [FB5, FB3, FC4]
c = [FF2, FB3, FM8]

Result = [FF2, FB3, FC4]
```

At the beginning I used the following code to compare 2 lists, and tried to adapt it for 3 lists, by adding an extra for loop after the `for i1` and also adding an or to my if, but went horribly wrong (almost 10 times more values as expected as output).

```
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    for i1, v1 in enumerate(b):
        if (i==i1) & (v==v1):
            Result.append(v)
```

This is my current approach, it's working fine, but I have no idea how can I append the matched value to my `Result` list.

```
Result = list(x for x, (xa, xb, xc) in enumerate(zip(a, b, c))
     if xa == xb or xb == xc or xa == xc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
al = ['FF2', 'FF6', 'FC4']
bl = ['FB5', 'FB3', 'FC4']
cl = ['FF2', 'FB3', 'FM8']

res = []
for a,b,c in zip(al, bl, cl):
    if a == b or b == c or c == a:
        if a == b:
            res.append(a)
        elif b == c:
            res.append(b)
        elif c == a:
            res.append(c)

print(res)
```

You can iterate through the 3 lists at the same time & append to the resulting list. Use `zip()`

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid the issues you're having by eliminating the use of `enumerate()` and just using `zip`. We then check each unique element in each tuple  created by `zip` and see if the count of that element is greater than 1. If so, we append this to our return list. The use of `t.count()` resolves the need for the untidy `xa == xb or xb == xc or xa == xc` condition & makes it easily extendable to `n` lists.

**Code:**

```
a = ['FF2', 'FF6', 'FC4']
b = ['FB5', 'FB3', 'FC4']
c = ['FF2', 'FB3', 'FM8']

r = [x for t in zip(a, b, c) for x in set(t) if t.count(x) > 1]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> r
['FF2', 'FB3', 'FC4']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this,

```
a = ["FF2", "FF6", "FC4"]
b = ["FB5", "FB3", "FC4"]
c = ["FF2", "FB3", "FM8"]

result = []
for idx in range(len(a)):
    if a[idx] == b[idx] or a[idx] == c[idx]:
        result.append(a[idx])
    elif b[idx] == c[idx]:
        result.append(b[idx])
    else:
        pass

print(result)
```

the **output** will be,

```
['FF2', 'FB3', 'FC4']
```